# Prevent AngularJS Controller call if unauthenticated

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic authentication check on route change which simply checks the existence of a SessionStorage key/val.  However, I have noticed that if an unauthenticated user navigates to a forbidden page who's controller contains an AJAX call, the AJAX call still happens in the background even though the forbidden page doesn't load and the user is instead redirected to login.  To get around this, I have added the same authentication check in every controller.  This is becoming a bit tedious and I was wondering if there is a better way, or a way I can globally check authentication before a controller's methods are run.  Here is the auth function on route change:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, authenticationService) {

    $rootScope.clearAlerts = function(){
        $rootScope.alerts = []
    }

    $rootScope.credentials = {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    };

    $rootScope.goto = function(url){
        $location.path(url);
    }

    $rootScope.authenticated = authenticationService.isLoggedIn()
    $rootScope.logOut = function () {
        authenticationService.logOut();
    }
    var publicRoutes = ['/login'];

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.credentials.from = $rootScope.desiredPath || '/login'
        $rootScope.authenticated = authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
        if (!_(publicRoutes).contains($location.path()) && !$rootScope.authenticated) {
            $rootScope.desiredPath = $location.path();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I would suggest checking out https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth rather than attempting to write your own auth interceptor from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should check authentication on server side and return appropriate message on client side

Below is the url help 
http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

and Write global handler in client side to check it

Below is a sample code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives'], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

    var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function (scope, $q) {

        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status;

            if (status == 401) {
                window.location = "./index.html";
                return;
            }
            // otherwise
            return $q.reject(response);

        }

        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }

    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```