# Prevent Default Routing - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

How can I *prevent default* the routing in angular 2? In ***router subscribe***, I get only the path name. I am not getting event in it. Is there any other service provider in angular 2 to get the route change event?

**app.component.js**

```
(function (app) {

app.AppComponent = ng.core
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
            directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
            viewProviders: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: [ng.router.Router, ng.http.Http, function (router, http) {

                   this.router.subscribe(function (pathname) {
                       //console.log(pathname);
                   });

            }],
        });

ng.router
        .RouteConfig([
          { path: '/login', component: app.LoginComponent, name: 'Login', useAsDefault: true },
          { path: '/todos', component: app.TodosComponent, name: 'Todos' },
        ])(app.AppComponent);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**boot.js**

```
(function (app) {

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ng.core.provide(ng.router.LocationStrategy, { useClass: ng.router.HashLocationStrategy })]);
    });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Can you help with this problem?

Comment: it's not very clear what you want to do. Do you want to prevent the default behavior of a link having a click handler for instance ?

Comment: `$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current){ })` In angular 1, _$routeChangeStart_ gives the event of the route change right? The same thing I need here in angular 2. I have used router subscribe for getting route changes. But I get only path name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `CanActivate` decorator in plain JS, you do the following:

```
var Child1Component = ng.core.Component({
  selector:'test',
  template: '<div>Test</div>'
}).Class({
  onSubmit: function(){
    console.log('onSubmit');
  }
});

ng.router.CanActivate((next, prev) => {
  // The Child1Component component is instantiated
  return true;

  // The Child1Component component isn't instantiated
  // return false;
})(Child1Component);
```

For example, at startup, the `prev` parameter is null and the `next` one contains the following:

```
ComponentInstruction {
  urlPath: "child1",
  urlParams: Array[0],
  terminal: true,
  specificity: "2",
  params: Object…
}
```

Comment: It is 100% working. Do I need to add `CanActivate` for every child component? Can I add `CanActivate` for **AppComponent** so that I can listen every time on route changes without need to add `CanActivate` for every child component?

Comment: Great! `CanActivate` must be defined for each component since it will allow the component to be instantiated or not...

Comment: Ok. Everything done. Thanks a lot for your help. I have learned a lot from you. Thank you

Comment: `CanActivate` is not working in angular 2 rc version. Can you give a correct code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@CanActivate()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) to prevent route change.

See also [Angular 2: Inject a dependency into @CanActivate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711962/angular-2-inject-a-dependency-into-canactivate) for current limitations.

Comment: Can you give a sample Javascript code for **CanActivate**?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. See comments above. The linked question has answers with code. You can also check out https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572

Comment: My question is simple. I need to prevent back button navigation after logging in. In angular 1, **$routeChangeStart** gives the **event, next, prev** when route changes. The same thing I need here in angular 2. How can I do this?

Comment: You question doesn't contain anything about this. I think you should edit your question and add this. I don't know Angular1. Do you actually want to prevent the back button or do you want to manipulate where the back button leads to? Why do you need this? `@CanActivate()` provides prev and next and when you return `false` the navigation is cancelled.

Comment: Now I understand. But I tried with the code `ng.router.CanActivate(function (next, prev) { return true; });`. It is not working. I cannot understand the **CanActivate** document clearly. Can you tell me the code to use **CanActivate** in Javascript?

Comment: I haven't used it myself yet and with Angular2 in JS I'm totally lost. I use only Dart.

Comment: CanActivate seems to be the right solution, if you want to prevent the login page to show up when user is logged in, you have to do that check in this decorator, if auth return false else return true

Comment: @Ludohen Can you send me the Javascript code to use **CanActivate**?