# ViewChild - Angular 2 Javascript

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

How can I use **ViewChild** in Angular 2 Javascript? I have referred **angular.io** docs and I have tried with the following code and it is not working. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**main.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.js**

```
(function (app) {

app.AppComponent = ng.core
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
            directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], //<----not loading components here
            viewProviders: [ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS],
            queries: {
                'viewChild1Component': new ng.core.ViewChild(app.Child1Component) //Parent calls Child 1 using ViewChild
            },
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: [ng.router.Router, ng.http.Http, function (router, http) {
                this.router = router;
                this.http = http;

            }],
            ngAfterViewInit: function () {
                this.viewChild1Component.onSubmit();
            },
        });

ng.router
        .RouteConfig([
          //loading components here
          { path: '/child1', component: app.Child1Component, name: 'Child 1', useAsDefault: true }, 
        ])(app.AppComponent);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**child1.js**

```
(function (app) {

    app.Child1Component = ng.core
            .Component({
                selector: 'test',
                template: '<div>Test</div>',
            })
            .Class({
                constructor: [ng.router.Router, function (router) {
                    this.router = router;
                }],
                onSubmit: function () {
                    alert('Call from Parent');
                },
            });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="scripts/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/system.js"></script>
    <!-- IE required polyfill -->
    <script src="scripts/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>

    <!--components-->
    <script src="app/components/child1.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/child2.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
    <script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
    <script src='app/boot.js'></script>

</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34573219/4933038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your field into the `queries` attribute of your component metadata, as described below:

```
var AppComponent = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: "app", 
    template:
      '<div>' +
      '  <test></test>' +
      '</div>',
    queries: {
      'subComponent': new ng.core.ViewChild(TestComponent) <-----
    },
    directives: [ TestComponent ]
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {
    },

    ngAfterViewInit:function(){
      this.subComponent.onSubmit();
    }
  });
```

The `subComponent` will set before the `ngAfterViewInit` hook is called.

The previous code relies on the following `TestComponent`:

```
var TestComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector:'test',
    template: '<div>Test</div>'
  }).Class({
    constructor: function(){
    },

    onSubmit: function(){
      console.log('onSubmit');
    }
  });
```

**Edit**

In your case, you leverage routing. This means that your `viewChild1Component` property will be set after the call of the `ngAfterViewInit` method since the `Child1Component` component is loaded in the `router-outlet` after. Things are dynamic in fact...

If you use the `viewChild1Component` property after (on a click for example), this will work... See the sample below:

```
app.AppComponent = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: "app", 
    template:
     '<div>' +
     '  <router-outlet></router-outlet>' +
     '  <div (click)="submit()">Submit</div>' +
     '</div>',
  queries: { 'viewChild1Component': new ng.core.ViewChild(Child1Component) },
  directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
.Class({
  submit: function() {
    console.log('#### submit');
    this.viewChild1Component.onSubmit();
  }
});
```

Comment: It's you again! Thanks and Love. I have tried your code and is working 100% fine. I understood your code and found the problem existing in my application is that I have used **Routing**. I don't load the component in template. I load the component in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` using `ng.router.RouteConfig`. Therfore I can't view the child in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding your last question, you try to reference a component loaded in `router-outlet` from the component that uses `router-outlet`. Right?

Comment: Yep. I don't load component in **directives**. I load component using **ng.router.RouteConfig**. I have edited this question. Please check it. You will get an idea of what I have done.

Comment: Okay, I see know. In fact, the sub component is loaded in `router-outlet` after the call of the `ngAfterViewInit` method. So the `viewChild1Component` property should be used later (on a click) for example. I updated my answer...

Comment: Working fine now. Thanks a lot. And I need 1 more help from you. I wanna know how to use **CanActivate** in Javascript. [My Post regarding CanActivate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794034/prevent-default-routing-angular-2). This is the link I have posted on. Please check this and help me to solve the problem

Comment: Thanking you again and again is not enough I think. My best wishes to you in everything

Comment: Is there an option to listen after the `router-outlet` component has been loaded?

Comment: You can leverage component lifecycle hooks (something like ngAfterViewInit). What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105697/discussion-between-abraham-a-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: Since I have used router-outlet, and you told that I can use `ViewChild` after the call of the `ngAfterViewInit` method. That is why I am asking like, Is there an option to listen after the `router-outlet`'s component has been loaded?

Comment: I can't add ViewChild queries in angular 2 rc version Can you help me to solve this issue? Can you give a correct code for this?

Comment: Can you look out my new question in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287510/viewchild-not-working-in-angular-2-rc-1-javascript) and solve my issue?

Comment: Will I use on behalf of EventEmitter? Or EventEmitter is a different concept? Because I am new to Angular 2 so... @ThierryTemplier