# ViewChild - Not working in Angular 2 RC 1 JavaScript

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-components

ViewChild is not woring in Angular 2 RC 1 JavaScript. I have used `<router-outlet>`. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance. Following is my sample code

```
app.AppComponent = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: "app", 
    template:
     '<div>' +
     '  <router-outlet></router-outlet>' +
     '  <div (click)="submit()">Submit</div>' +
     '</div>',
  queries: { 'viewChild1Component': new ng.core.ViewChild(app.Child1Component) },
  directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
.Class({
  submit: function() {
    console.log('#### submit');
    this.viewChild1Component.onSubmit();
  }
});

ng.router
        .Routes([
          { path: '/child1', component: app.Child1Component, useAsDefault: true },
        ])(app.AppComponent);
```

Comment: Just use a shared service to communicate with components added by the router. I guess `@ViewChild` is not supposed to work in this case.

Comment: can you see the same [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BEzo8eH4b4NChHKZppGd?p=preview) ? i have updated with `@ViewChild`. clicking on Alert button in AppComponent doesn't trigger alert method in LoginComponent.

Comment: As mentioned above, I would not expect this to work.

Comment: but in previous versions, this worked right? even i have tried it in previous versions. also can you explain me when we use `@ViewChild`?

Comment: I never tried with routed components. You can use it to get a reference to components and elements in the view. If it worked before, I would create a bug report.

Comment: can you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847818/viewchild-angular-2-javascript?lq=1). i have asked before and i got the answer even for `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. i am damn sure about that the `@ViewChild` was worked well before.

Comment: For me, it's not working even without a router. That's about querying components. However, querying directives works.