# Disabling back button in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, pushstate

I've looked all over StackOverflow and Google and haven't been able to find anything that's really working out for me. I need to disable the back button in my Angular app when a user reaches a certain page in the flow. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: @mberacochea Angular uses push state, so it's a tad different. And I'm not trying to modify the URL.

Comment: This approach using a listener + canDeactivate guard may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402713/5499369

Comment: @MarkLeong canDeactivate guard doesn't work since it breaks router history https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13586