# I want to remove all the previous routing history when a user logs in successfully so that he cant go back to login page by clicking back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to remove all the previous routing history after successful login of a user. i was using angular router and replaceUrl is only removing that specific route from the history stack, not the entire history. I cant use Nav Controller because that is deprecated. Is there any way that i can achieve this with angular router?

Comment: This answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56354475/12914833

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Browser back button in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357204/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-in-angular-2)

Comment: @ChrisHamilton thanks brother. worked for me with some changes according to my use case. Thank you very much and good luck.

Comment: @TheFabio issue got fixed by the method suggested by chris above. Thank you for the effort. Good luck