# Angular browser back button

Tags: angular, browser, back

I want to implement a pop on browser back button in angular. I have used popstate as well as angular location api but nothing working as expected, can anyone suggest some solution

I have tried location api as well as popstate with host listener

Comment: What's the actual problem? Showing the popup... or preventing the browser back button functionality? I found this when searching "prevent browser back button Angular": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357204/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-in-angular-2

Comment: Main problem is that when I click on back button it should show a pop up asking "do you want to log out?" , it shows the pop up but on multiple click it is redirected to previous page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])` and when it is triggered show your pop.

Comment: Tried this but on multiple click on back button it is behaving unexpectedly

Comment: Then you can add property which indicates if pop opened and if it is just do nothing when the button clicked.