# Inject Router using Injector.resolveAndCreate inside a class

Tags: angular, router

Is it possible to inject  Router using Injector.resolveAndCreate() ?

```html
import {ExceptionHandler, Injectable, Inject,Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from 'angular2/router';

@Injectable()
export class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler{

    constructor(public router: Router) { }
    call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
        console.log("ERROR >> " + error);
        console.log("STACKTRACE >> " + stackTrace);
        console.log("REASON >> " + reason);
        let injector: any = Injector.resolveAndCreate([Router]);
        let router: Router = injector.get(Router);
        router.navigateByUrl('/error');       
        
    }
}
```

Getting EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Token RouterPrimaryComponent! (e -> Router -> RouteRegistry -> Token RouterPrimaryComponent).

Comment: Have you tried it? (the answer as you would have discovered would be yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you use an injector that has `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` registered, but you usually don't want **a** `Router` instance but **the** `Router` instance - the one used in the application. For this you need to use the same `Injector` as the Angular application uses.

This might be what you are looking for [Redirect to a different component inside @CanActivate in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711889/redirect-to-a-different-component-inside-canactivate-in-angular2/35064841#35064841)

Comment: Thanks @Gunter. I have updated the code and the error i am getting .Can you please take a look .

Comment: I don't think what your updated code shows is what you actually want. You'd get a different `Router` instance than the one used by Angular. Don't you get the `Router` instance passed already to your `constructor(...)`?

Comment: The router passed in the constructor is null

Comment: Can you please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried to your question?