# Angular 2 Custom Error Handling and Router

Tags: angular

I have a custom exception handler that is supposed to take the user to a custom error page if any exception occurs(just trying it out).

I am trying to get the instance of the router using Injector.
Reason for doing this, I believe the injector will give the existing router instance and using it i will be able to route the user.

Any ideas why this is not working or how this can be achieved ?

Thank You :)

```
@Injectable()
export class AppExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler{

constructor(){
    super(null, null);
}

call(exception:any, stackTrace?:any, reason?:string):void {
    console.log('call...')


    var providers = Injector.resolve([ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
    var injector = Injector.fromResolvedProviders(providers);

    // this is causing issue, not sure it is the correct way
    let router : Router = injector.get(Router);

    // not executed
    console.log(router)

    // not executed 
    console.log('done...')
    router.navigate(["CustomErrorPage"]);
    }

}
```

---

**Answer** - tested in 2.0.0-beta.17
Thanks to [Druxtan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711889/redirect-to-a-different-component-inside-canactivate-in-angular2)

```
1. Created a file app.injector.ts inside the app folder (app/app.injector.ts)
```

```
let appInjectorRef;

export const appInjector = (injector?) => {
    if (!injector) {
        return appInjectorRef;
    }

    appInjectorRef = injector;

    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

```
2. Added to the bootstrap in the main.ts
```

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS,provide(ExceptionHandler,{useClass : AppExceptionHandler})])
    .then((appRef) => appInjector(appRef.injector));
```

```
3. In the AppExceptionHandler, retrieved the Router instance as shown below
```

```
export class AppExceptionHandler {

    call(exception:any, stackTrace?:any, reason?:string):void {

        let injectorApp = appInjector();
        let router = injectorApp.get(Router);
        let localStorageService = injectorApp.get(LocalStorageService);

        if(exception.message === '-1'){
            localStorageService.clear();
            router.navigate(["Login"]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: hi updated the question with answer. :)

Comment: I would love an update to this question for Angular6

Answer (score 1):

I would implement your feature this way since this class takes place in the dependency injection:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    super(null, null);
  }

  call(exception:any, stackTrace?:any, reason?:string):void {
    console.log('call...')

    this.router.navigate(['CustomErrorPage']);
  }
}
```

and register your handle this way:

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [
  provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: AppExceptionHandler})
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion
Initially it was done this way. It still gave me problems. From the error message it looked like the AppExceptionHandler is initialized before the Router therefore it cant be injected.

I tried this too

`bootstrap(MyApp, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: AppExceptionHandler})
]);`

even that didnt work, that is why i swithced to Injector.