# Rxjs conditionally make a second http call

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to understand rxjs (6) and how I should call conditionally make a second http post.

My scenario is that:

1. I am/have uploaded a file.
2. I get an object identifying the current progress and a filename.
3. If the current progress is 100 I want to make the second http post and on success of that second call return the progress and the filename
4. If the current progress is less than 100 simply return the progress and filename

**My class**

```
export class BasePortalDetailsManagerService {
   updateCertificate(file: File): Observable<IUploadProgress> {
    return this._azureBlobStorage
               .uploadCertificateToBlobStorage2(file, this.portalKey)
               .pipe(
                  map(progress => this.mapProgress2(progress))
                );
  }

  private mapProgress2(fileProgress: FileProgress): IUploadProgress {
    if (fileProgress.Progress === 100) {
      console.log('I can do something here but there must be a better way');

    } else {
      return {
        filename: fileProgress.FilePath,
        progress: fileProgress.Progress
      };
    }
  }   
}
```

I have been watching and reading various stuff and the only that seems to happen is, it convinces me my way is wrong. I cant seem to get my head round the various tutorials.

**various links I've followed**

[rxjs quick start](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/rxjs-quickstart-with-20-examples/)

[cory rylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

[rxjs where is the if/else](https://blog.rangle.io/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/)

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610150/rxjs-condition-inside-flatmap/47610715#47610715

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue thanks to @martin pointing me in the right direction.

I change `mapProgress2()` return type to be `Observable<IUploadProgress>` then use flatMap to flatten the inner observable.

My knowledge of rxjs is very limited but I believe for scenario `flatMap`, `switchMap` or `concatMap` would suffice. @martin suggested `concatMap` and after reading the docs I agree.

From [The RXJS docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io)

> flatMap: flatMap is an alias for mergeMap!
>
> mergeMap: If you would like more than one inner subscription to be maintained, try mergeMap
>
> switchMap: If only one inner subscription should be active at a time, try switchMap
>
> concatMap:  If the order of emission and subscription of inner observables is important, try concatMap

```
updateCertificate(file: File): Observable<IUploadProgress> {
  return this._azureBlobStorage
             .uploadCertificateToBlobStorage2(file, this.portalKey)
             .pipe(
                flatMap(progress => this.mapProgress2(progress))
              );
}

private mapProgress2(fileProgress: IUploadProgress): Observable<IUploadProgress> {
  if (fileProgress.progress === 100) {
    return this._httpClient.post(this._portalDetails + 'certificatePath', JSON.stringify(fileProgress.filename))
               .pipe(map(res => fileProgress));
  } else {
    return Observable.create(function(observer) {
      observer.next(fileProgress);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `map` use `concatMap` and depending on `progress` return this original object wrapped in an Observable with `of(progress)` or return another Observable that makes the second request and map its result to `progress`:

```
this._azureBlobStorage.uploadCertificateToBlobStorage2(file, this.portalKey).pipe(
  concatMap(progress => progress.Progress === 100
    ? this.mapProgress2(progress).pipe(
        map(filename => ({ // This could go inside `mapProgress2` as well
          filename: progress.FilePath,
          progress: progress.Progress
        })),
      )
    : of(progress)
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm feeling a little lost as I can't call pipe on mapProgress2 as it only returns IUploadProgress, not an observable. Also do I make my second http call in of or concatMap?