# Redirect to login page if user is in logout state, Angular2

Tags: angular, routes

I am developing a single page app using AngularJS2, I want to redirect to login page if user is not login, how can I check condition for each route to check for login?

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { SalesComponent } from './sales/sales.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'employees', component: EmployeeComponent },
  { path: '404-not-found', component: NotFoundComponent },
  { path: 'logout', component : LogoutComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404-not-found' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I want to check for login status in app.routing.ts file, and if I am not login I should redirect to login.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answers at [Angular2 redirect to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331478/angular2-redirect-to-login-page?rq=1)

The solution using CanActivate interface implementation is a robust solution with the current release of the new Router.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create auth service and auth guard service as explained on [Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) document and need to configure it in route config.