# Getting errors on ng-serve

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I am trying to use angular cli and getting following error:

> ERROR in multi
>   script-loader!./src/assets/vendors/by_bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js

Actually what I did is :

1. npm install -g @angular/cli;
2. npm install
3. ng serve

In package.json I have 
 "@angular/cli": "latest",

on ng serve I am getting this error.

After google I came to know that this [can be issue of version of Angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5665). Please help how to get rid of this.

Edit:

On ng serve verbose I am getting:

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  3.7 kB       0
    chunk    {0} index.html 1.04 kB [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Failed to compile.

** Actually I am trying to run a purchased theme.

Comment: do `ng serve --verbose` and post the result so we can see what's the issue.

Comment: I think the issue comes on loading asset. Can you please help me in this ..

Comment: Based on what im seeing, the cli is throwing a very unhelpful message. First, try deleting the node_module folder then run npm install. If that does not work, try removing all scripts then add them one by one running 'ng serve' after each to check which one is throwing the error.

Comment: Also, please post your package.json and .angular-cli.json so i can try and replicate.

Comment: .angular-cli.json  file as well please.

Comment: @Ahmed: Thanks a lot, but the issue was I was in need to hit bower install after npm install.

Comment: oh.. I dont see bower in your dependencies.. also your js files are under this path: /src/assets/vendors/by_bower ?? strange. anyway, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was in need of a "bower install" command.

Hope if it helps some one.

Thanks.