# CORS issues when doing redirection from .net core web api

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

> Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://somedevserver.com/SomePage?id=abc' (redirected from
> 'https://localhost:44359/api/Verification/signin') from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not
> allowed for a preflight request.

I have enabled CORS policy in Verification service and hence the call from localhost:4200 goes to Verification/signin method.
The logic inside Verification/signin created URL http://somedevserver.com/SomePage?id=abc successfully and tries to performs a redirection.

The redirection is done using following code:

```
[Route("signin")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> Signin([FromBody] ApiQuery request)
{
    ApiResponse response = await Mediator.Send(request);
    return RedirectPermanent(response.SomeEndpoint);
}
```

Redirection happens successfully in SoapUI when I tested Verification/signin method. However, when I integrate the Verification/signin method in Angular app, the redirection fails due to CORS issue.

Do I need to set any headers inside Verification/signin method before the redirection is performed and/or inside localhost:4200 when the web api call is made?

```
somedevserver.com/SomePage?id=abc -> .Net application

Verification/signin -> .Net Core 5.0 Web Api

localhost:4200 -> Angular 11 App
```

I have managed to resolved the pre-flight OPTION request issue by adding code in `Global.asax.cs -> Application_BeginRequest` method. Now all the pre-flight request are successful, however, the browser still don't redirect.

I can see the HTML coming up in F12 -> Response tab however the redirection is not happening.

Do I need to add any special headers before `return RedirectPermanent(response.SomeEndpoint);`

Comment: Can you u update the  response headers?

Comment: @Phalgun: I can update the header, what would you like me to add in response?

Comment: ,My bad, I meant can you update the question to include the response headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue is by design. Server redirections are not applicable to Single Pages Apps.

For my understanding you have 2 applications:

- Angular frontend
- dotnet core api backend

The entire Angular application is loaded on first browse and runs on a browser: every route is managed client side. The only way to contact the server is via apis.

In this context redirecting an api XHR background request does not trigger a browser redirect.

You can achieve your goal returning an api http error like this on backend side:

```
401 Unauthorized
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "details": "You need to login"
}
```

Than you can manage this "standard" http errors with an Angular AuthGuard like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968963/3120219

Comment: I agree, the design is wrong here. What I did is, from Angular I made a html post request(not ajax) and inside the api I kept the redirect code as-is. This made the browser triggered the redirection based on the response which came from api i.e. 301/302 and location information.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be to set up a proxy for the local development server.
I have often used this to avoid having to fiddle with server configurations.
For example, your local server is running on `http://localhost:4200/` and the server is running on `http://localhost:8080/`.
Basically, you need to create a "proxy.config.json" file in the src/ folder of your Angular project.

In this file, you need to put something like:

```
{  
   "/api": {
     "target": "http://localhost:8080",
     "secure": false
   }
}
```

And then you can start your application with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`. See the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server) post.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the error message: "Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request". So I suppose you need to setup the redirecting server to return a normal response (200) for all preflight requests (request type - "OPTIONS"), and after that make a redirect for the main request (request type not "OPTIONS").

Comment: Thanks, I have already managed to resolve the error by handling the OPTION request in Global.asax.cs -> Application_BeginRequest method. Now all the pre-flight are successful, however, the browser still don't redirect.