# How to get a status code when Cross-Origin Request Blocked using angular httpclient

Tags: angular, http, angular-httpclient

I have this code

```
  public post(url) {
    return this.http
      .post(url, formData {
        headers,
        responseType: 'text',
      })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

error handler:

```
  handleError(error) {
    // do some logic

    return of(0);
  }
```

I call that function `this.post('url').subscibe(console.log)` when the api failed I've got 0 in return, but what I want is to being able to return a status code.

If I inspect the error object what I see is

```
status: 0    ​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
message: "Http failure response
```

Here is the full error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
> reading the remote resource at https:....... (Reason: CORS header
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Just for test if I hit the same api with the same params using Postman I see that here is a status code there

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

So I need to get that `Status code: 200` within Angular Http Client

I've tried to add `observe: 'response'` but seems all the same

```
.post(url, formData {
            headers,
            responseType: 'text',
             observe: 'response'
          })
```

Comment: Hello Sreginogemoh, You can use Angular Interceptor for checking the status code of API calls

Comment: Hi sreginogemoh, using `observe: response` should be correct to access the status when no error occurs [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors). If an error occurs, you only return `of(0)`, instead you could return the error itself which also contains the status information, like `error.status` -> [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors).

Comment: @riorudo see I console log the error object, the error `status` is `0` and `statusText` is `Unknown Error` but I would expect the `status` to be `200`

Comment: @riorudo based on the docs `if (error.status === 0) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error);
  }` so that is what I receive but it is seems that angular http client changing that from `200` to `0`. I have a prove that it is `200` in console error message + sending same request using postman as stated in the question.

Comment: It seems that you have a CORS problem. Probably your local application is running on port "4200" and the server on another port. This is actually a browser "problem". You can solve this server-side or locally for your application. If you want to try the second approach, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941665/8712609).

Comment: This may be an intentional consequence of the Same Origin Policy (that CORS is an extension of). That is, the browser may be intentionally blocking your access to the status code, since you're not authorized to read the response.

Comment: @riorudo I have no control over server-side

Comment: I've done a bit more research, it is seems a browser-related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325314/how-to-detect-cross-origin-cors-error-vs-other-types-of-errors-for-xmlhttpreq so seems that when `cors error` browsers set status to `0`